# unable to load app with loader

Tags: iphone, submission

i'm trying to submit my app, i have builded in simulator, then click on the xcode folder products, right click on myapp.app show in finder, zipped that file and used loader to upload.

but i receice this issues:
iphone/ipod touch: application executable is missing required architecture. at least one of the following must be present: armv6

> > but if i click on the project->targets in architecture i have standard(armv6 armv7)
> >     icon dimension (58x58) don't meet the size requirements. the icon must be 57x57
> >     the icon was 58x58, so i have made it 57x57 but still get this error

application failed codesign verification. the signature was invalid, or it was signed with an apple submission certificate

> > i made a new app store distribution profile and putted in code sign->debug but still this error occours

any ideas?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't submit an app built for the simulator, as the architecture will then be i386.

You need to build it for the iOS device (ARM).

By the way, why do you use the application loader? If using Xcode 4, you can build an archive from it (Menu > Product > Archive ).

Once complete, it will show the organizer, and you'll be able to validate and submit your app from there.

About the code signing issues, try a search here (this topic was covered many, many times), or simply check your build settings to see if the app has a valid code-signing option.

Comment: thanks, i had searched a lot, found old tutorial, after what you have submitted, i tryed but still got errors, but after many many attempt i could make it work thanks